# android menu items do not display

Tags: android, menu

there is an activity in my android application. I override the 'onCreateOptionsMenu' method, adding four menu items in the activity. But the menu items do not display. I can not figure out what is the problem. Could somebody give me an clue to fix that or explaination?

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, FeaturedActivity.MENU_FEATURED, 0, R.string.menu_featured).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tabbar_featured);

    menu.add(0, FeaturedActivity.MENU_THE_DRINK, 1, R.string.menu_the_drink).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tabbar_drinks);

    menu.add(0, FeaturedActivity.MENU_PLAYER, 2, R.string.menu_player).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tabbar_player);

    menu.add(0, FeaturedActivity.MENU_SHARE, 3, R.string.menu_share).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_tabbar_share);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: pressing menu was the answer to your question !?

Answer (score 1):

in your activity use

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.info:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutApp.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and create a folder menu in **res** and now create an xml in **res/menu** like optionsmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/info" android:title="Info"
        android:icon="@drawable/info_menubtn" />
    <item android:id="@+id/exit" android:title="Exit" />
</menu>
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

remove the line   **super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)**; and try .

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        menu.add("this is menu");
        menu.add("this is another");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

edit into above code and add `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` at last and remove it from first line

Comment: http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/building-a-menu-for-your-android-v10-r1-app/